# Having an MS Office UserForm detect which subroutine called it

Tags: vba, excel, userform

In a VBA project of mine I am/will be using a series of reasonably complex userforms, many of which are visually identical but have different subroutines attached to the buttons. As a result I'm not overly keen on the idea of duplicating them multiple times in order to get different functionality out of the same layout. Is it possible to have a userform detect which subroutine called it and use this in flow control? I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    If [the sub that called the userform is called "foo"] then
        Call fooSub
    else
        Call barSub
    End If
End Sub
```

My backup plan is to have the calling subroutine set a global variable flag and have the userform check that, but that seems like a rather crude and clumsy solution.

Thanks everyone,
Louis

Comment: You could put a hidden `Label` form control on your userform, and have the calling routine change the `.Caption` of that label, then use an `If/Then` or `Select Case` statement to evaluate the `.Caption`, and send off to the appropriate subroutine(s).

Comment: Is there any advantage to this over a global variable flag?

Comment: Probably not, but IMO it seems like a tidier solution than a global variable. I like HeadOfCatering's response but it gives me a compile error. If it's working for you, though, I say use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tag property of the form. Load the form, set the property, then show the form:

```
Sub PassCallerToForm()
    Load UserForm1
    UserForm1.Tag = "foo"
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Now that the property is set, you can determine what to do in the form:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    If Me.Tag = "foo" Then
        Call fooSub
    Else
        Call barSub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting solution but when I try to use this, I get a compile error: `Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name`

Comment: Heh, I was wrong. You can't pass in arguments to the Initialize event of a form. I've revised the answer and tested it. This method works.

Comment: Heh! I should probably not have marked your answer as correct before I tested it. That's a lesson for me. I like your new solution the most as well so that's ok. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, it looked like it should work. Sonofa! I'm glad the revised solution works as well. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use public variables:

```
' in userform

Public Caller As String

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    MsgBox Caller
    Caller = Now()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

' in caller
Sub callUF()
    Dim frm As New UserForm1
    frm.Caller = "Test Caller"
    frm.Show
    MsgBox frm.Caller ' valid after Me.Hide
    Set frm = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read my post, I already considered global variables as a solution.

Comment: The Public Caller in the example is not a global variable - it is located on the form.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would not have one userform doing two disparate activities. The code would get hard to read pretty quickly, I think.  Copying the layout of a userform is pretty trivial.

To copy a userform: Open a blank workbook. In the Project Explorer, drag the userform to the new workbook. Rename the userform in the new workbook. Now drag it back to the original workbook. Change the code in the userform copy.

If you absolutely don't want separate userforms, I recommend setting up a property of the userform. Userforms are just classes except they have a user interface component.  In the userform module

```
Private mbIsFoo As Boolean

Public Property Let IsFoo(ByVal bIsFoo As Boolean): mbIsFoo = bIsFoo: End Property
Public Property Get IsFoo() As Boolean: IsFoo = mbIsFoo: End Property

Public Sub Initialize()

    If Me.IsFoo Then
        FooSub
    Else
        BarSub
    End If

End Sub
```

I always write my own Initialize procedure.  In a standard module:

```
Sub OpenForm()

    Dim ufFooBar As UFooBar

    Set ufFooBar = New UFooBar

    ufFooBar.IsFoo = True
    ufFooBar.Initialize

    ufFooBar.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: I agree, having one useform with two functions is not ideal but these userforms have a great number of labels, textboxes, etc, and the renaming them from the defaults to something useful would be really very tedious. Thank you for your thoughts, I like your solution a lot. Having your own initialize procedure is rather cool.